# SpringBoot says "Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

I am using a form, and when I hit submit it hits the following controller.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ViewController
{
    private final static String USERNAME = "username";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "password";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authenticate()
    {
        return "authenticate.html";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/connector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String connector(final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    final String username = request.getParameter(USERNAME);
    final String password = request.getParameter(PASSWORD);

    session.setAttribute(USERNAME, username);
    session.setAttribute(PASSWORD, password);
    return "connectors.html";
}
}
```

I know the method is being hit as I have placed breakpoints in it.  However, I still get the above mentioned error.

Edit: I have posted the entire controller rather than just the method.
Edit2: My html form is as follows:

```
    <form action="/connector" method="post" name="authentication_form">
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

        <a href = "javascript:document.authentication_form.submit();" class="link-next">
                    Next
                    <i class="ico-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    </form>
```

What am I missing?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your full controller class

Comment: I have edited my post to show the full class @Reimeus

Comment: Please add the html form that you're are using

Comment: Are you using, Spring security or any kind of security ?

Comment: Only what Spring-Boot web includes

Comment: The problem shows up when you load the JSP ? o when you submit the form ?

Comment: kind of both.  The initial page shows...I submit the form, I know it is hitting the break points in the method above, but then instead of showing the next page...I get the 405 error

Comment: look at this http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/ae00afcaaf4f/request-method-post-not-supported-in-spring-mvc.html

Comment: Those don't seem to get me any closer to a solution

Comment: When I change the form action to "GET" and the method to "GET" it works just fine, the problem only occurs when I use POST

Comment: 1. In the method public String connector(final HttpServletRequest request){}, can you try using different params, like public String connector(@RequestBody RequestPOJO request){}. 2. You can also add a return type in the @RequestMapping(produces = "XX/YY"). 3. You can hit the REST app using a external app like Postman, just to check if it is not related to the way the requets is made by the web app. 4. If you are able to enter the method, then the problem lies in processing the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using @RestController annotation instead of @Controller ?

Comment: I did, and it only returns a String that says "connectors.html"

Comment: Since you ask to return that string, I don't understand what is the problem about that.

Comment: I want it to return my actual html page

Answer (score 0):

I had to create another method that uses GET and redirect to it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String connector(final HttpServletRequest request, final AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials )
{
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("Authentication", authenticationCredentials);

    return "redirect:/test";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String connector()
{
    return "steve.html";
}
```